# Docker containers having trouble exposing ports to host on Mac

Tags: linux, macos, docker, docker-machine

I was trying to expose a port from the Docker container on which my server is running to my Mac host so that my browser on the host can access it.

I could use `run -it -p <port>:<port> ...` command to expose a port. That certainly works on Linux host (I have been doing that all the time before with no  problem). But never worked on my Mac. By "never worked", I mean no ports from the container side is exposed at all even though the `docker ps` commands did show the mapping like this `0.0.0.0:32769->8080/tcp`. But nothing could be connected.

So I am wondering if there is any extra-configuration I have to do to make it happen. I am using macOS Sierra 10.12 and Docker version 1.11.1, build 5604cbe.

Any input will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you testing locally, or from another machine on the network? If you're trying to connect from another host, it's probably a firewall issue.

Comment: Are you using the "native" Docker for Mac, or Docker Machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Docker Toolbox, you need to make sure to get the right Docker machine IP address.

`docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name webserver nginx`

Find the right IP with `docker-machine ip`. You might get `192.168.99.100`.

Then you can check it by open web browser at `http://192.168.99.100:8080/` with out proxy.

If you're using Docker for Mac, please read this [docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/).